# Group an image and a rectangle together in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My problem is I have an image that represents a plane , and a rectangle that represents the area that is captured and saved as an image. yet when moving them around the WPF they move at different speeds even though they are are told to go at the same speeds.

Is there a way I can group them together in some tag so they are viewed as one object but separate at the same time? I need them separate as the size of the rectangle should be able to change where as the image of the plane should not.

xaml:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="RED" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="89" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" Margin="349,204,0,0"/>
<Image x:Name="planeIMG" Source="plane.PNG" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="367,213,369,335"/>
```

code behind it for going left (it is identical for the others)

```
if ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.A) & KeyStates.Down) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test left key is pressed ");
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(rect.Margin.Left -10 , rect.Margin.Top, rect.Margin.Right, rect.Margin.Bottom);
            planeIMG.Margin = new Thickness(planeIMG.Margin.Left -10, planeIMG.Margin.Top, planeIMG.Margin.Right, planeIMG.Margin.Bottom);
        }
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: just embed them in a `Grid`

Answer (score 0):

Just like Chris W. mentioned: Just chuck them in a grid.

I advise you to try and move the MVVM pattern when using WPF and took the liberty to write a little sample. Define a viewmodel for your moving item (which is a grid containing the image and rectangle).

```
 class MovingItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public Thickness Margin { get; set; }
    public String Data { get; set; }

    public ICommand MoveRightCommand { get; set; }

    public MovingItemViewModel() {
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Data = "Hello!";
        MoveRightCommand = new RelayCommand(param => MoveRight());
    }

    public void MoveRight() {
        Console.WriteLine("Right Key is pressed!");
        double offset = Margin.Right - 10;
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, offset, 0);
        OnPropertyChanged("Margin");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null ) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here I use the RelayCommand class to route user input to the viewmodel. You can read more about RelayCommand [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented to notify the view of changes in the viewmodel.

In your view, which will probably be just the main window, you call the MoveRight method via key bindings. The position of the grid is bound to the margin property of the viewmodel.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=MoveRightCommand}" 
  Key="Right" ></KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="{Binding Thickness}" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Blue">
        <Label Content="I like to move it!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Move it!" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You can substitute the label and textbox with an image and a rectangle if you wish.

Finally, in the code behind of the view you define the datacontext.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MovingItemViewModel vm = new MovingItemViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
```

This is meant not only to answer your question (which I hope it does) but also to give you a quick insight to MVVM. There are heaps of more in-depth information to be found on the web.